How to perform OpenAPI request validation with style simple + path variables as object
I want to perform request validation with OpenAPI 3.0.x with style: simple and path variables as object. As per the OAS specification document, I want to have below configuration in my API for path variables.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/




style
Object id = {"role": "admin", "firstName": "Alex"}




simple
/users/role,admin,firstName,Alex



my backend apis should be as below:
http://test-api/users/role,admin,firstName,Alex

how to create yml file for this configuration?
i tried a couple of workarounds but its not working and giving me json parsing error

openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: My API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /users/{id}:
    get:
      summary: my api endpoint
      operationId: getUsersById
      parameters:
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/path_id"
      responses: 
        '200':
          description: OK
          content: 
            application/json: 
              schema: {}
        '400':
            description: Bad Request
            content:
              'application/problem+json':
                schema: 
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/problem_json"
components: 
  parameters: 
    path_id:
      name: id
      in: path
      style: simple
      explode: false
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          role:
            enum:
            - admin
            - user
          firstName:
            type: string
  schemas:
    problem_json:
      title: RFC9457 - Problem JSON
      description: Problem Details for HTTP APIs - RFC9457
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          format: 'uri-reference'
        status:
          type: number
        title:
          type: string
        detail:
          type: string
        instance:
          type: string
          format: 'uri-reference'
    


I am getting same json parsing error after above yaml configurations.
13:25:46.581 [main] DEBUG io.swagger.v3.parser.util.ResolverFully - avoiding infinite loop
Request is invalid:
ERROR - Unable to parse JSON - Unrecognized token 'role': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
  at [Source: (String)"role,admin,firstName,Alex"; line: 1, column: 5].: []


Could be the package doesn't support path and style keywords.create an issue on the GitHub repo

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/17283
